# pointer to pointer to c++ class and initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I need to make an array of pointers to a C++ class, let's call it class A and it should be a static element of that same class class:

```
class A{

public:
  static A** array;
}
```

The number of elements of that array is unknown. How can I allocate and reallocate memory for that array?

Comment: To begin with, whenever you need a "dynamic array" your next thought should be [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Why don't you use a `std::vector` ? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg why array of pointers prompts you to use a vector instead? what about A** and using some new and delete?

Comment: @noob Because of "A** and using some new and delete".

Comment: @noob, because `std::vector` will manage those things for you (correctly), leaving you to only worry about your actual application logic, instead of debugging the wheel you re-invented.

Comment: I see. But won't that cause overhead (not noticeable, but still) in run-time?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I will try it.

Comment: @noob Don't try to optimize your code before writing it and measuring it effectively needs optimization

Comment: @noob by that logic, you should program in machine language. Use higher abstractions (e.g. `std::vector`). The benefits are huge and the overhead is minimal

Comment: @noob, Even if it does, you can only credibly say that after profiling your code and seeing this is a bottleneck. But to answer you question, most likely no. Your own implementation will not do any less than `std::vector` does, and it will probably lack any optimizations that library writers can add.

Comment: Vectors work perfectly but, unfortunately my assignment does not allow usage of std::vector. So I will have to deal with new and delete! Thanks anyways!

Comment: If you *must* use pointers and manual allocation/deallocation, then read about the `new[]` and `delete[]` operators, plus [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (because there's no way to actually reallocate, only to allocate new and copy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## With raw pointers:

The code below is just to explain.

```
size_t num_elem = 123;  // Dynamic number of elements

// Allocation
A::array = new A*[num_elem];  // Dynamic Allocation
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elem; ++i) {
  A::array[i] = new A();  // Allocation of each A in the array.
}

// Deallocation
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elem; ++i) {
 delete A::array[i];  // Dealloce each instance of A.
}
delete[] A::array;  // Deallocation
A::array = nullptr;  // Safety reason
```

## With Vector Container and Smart Pointer

As some comments suggest you, this is a *safer* way.

**EDIT**:*I assume you need an array of array and A must to be dynamically allocate as well. Moreover in order to make safer, I suggest you to use [smart pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).*

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

// ...
size_t num_elem = 123;  // Dynamic number of elements
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> array(num_elem);  // Now array contains 123 pointers to A.


// Allocation
for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elem; ++i) {
  array[i] = std::make_unique<A>(/*obj contruction*/);  // Allocation of each A in the array.
}

// Deallocation
array.clear();
```

Comment: it's not only it's the /simpler. Most importantly it's the **safer** way. And in the `std::vector` example you are still using `new` and `delete`. To see why you want to avoid manual memory management (i.e. explicitly calling `new`) tell me what happens when a constructor of `A` throws in the middle of your loop allocation. Do you see the memory leak?

Comment: @bolov yeah! They're pointer anyway. You could use a `std::unique_ptr<A>` in order to make safer, but the answer would be OT.

Comment: You've made an implicit assumption about the class needing to be allocated dynamically as well. This could just as easily be a simple tracking device for instances.